# How do you create a typescript decorator that makes the decorated class extend a class

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I have very limited knowledge in creating decorators so please bear with me.

Let say we have a base class which we will use later for our decorator:

```
export class BaseElement { 
     tag: string;
     // some other stuff the base class will do
}
```

We have a decorator called `Component`, the parameters of which we would use to set the properties of the base class

```
@Component({
  tag: 'todo-list',
})
export class TodoList { }
```

Here the decorated class is `TodoList` it should extend `BaseClass` when the decorator `Component` constructs our desired class
and sets the `tag` property from the decorator parameters:

This is what I wanted to achieve using the decorator:

```
export class TodoList extends BaseElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.tag = ‘todo-list’;
    }
}
```

If this is not possible , is there a way to create a typescript ‘plugin’ to make this possible?

Comment: All parameters from your decorator will be declared on the base class ?

Comment: Yes, which would make this look useless, but this is just an example. The base class will do more than just this.

Comment: My question is if you want the decorator to add fields/methods that are in neither the base class or the decorated class ? A decorator can't do that, neither can id change the base class (it can't change the structure of the decorated type, by design).

Comment: No. So would this be possible using a custom transform?